# Getting just the upper case letters from a string

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I have just started to learn python and I'm just making programs to practice the new topic I have learnt, so please be gentle :)

I try to have a var = to a sentence then check for upper case letters then append the upper case letters to a list. If I change `l = o[6]` I get 'G' so the append and `.isupper()` is working but I can't seem to get the `i` to work, I thought it might be `i` is becoming a string but `i` is declared as a an int (python 3.6).

This is what i have so far:

```
o = "the doG jUmPeD ovEr The MOOn"
upperCase = []
i = 0
l = o[i]

if l.isupper() == True:
   upperCase.append(l)

else:
    i += 1

print (upperCase)
```

Comment: you need to use a loop

Comment: I think you need to spend some time with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html). It's a great tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was just throwing a few things together that i have learnt and seeing if I understood what i had learnt.

Comment: Some text cleaning, highlight variables in text, added `uppercase` tag to mean `.usupper()` check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to build up this list. A `for` loop is very simple to build in Python. It simply iterates over all the letters one by one. Try to modify the code to,

```
o = "the doG jUmPeD ovEr The MOOn"
upperCase = []
for i in range(0, len(o)):
    l = o[i]  
    if l.isupper() == True:
       upperCase.append(l)

print (upperCase)
```

---

Of course, there are better ways to do it. You don't need to explicitely define `l = o[i]`. You can do that as part of the loop! Also, you don't need the `== True`. Something like this -

```
o = "the doG jUmPeD ovEr The MOOn"
upperCase = []
for l in o:
    if l.isupper():
       upperCase.append(l)

print (upperCase)
```

---

Even better, use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

```
print(filter(lambda l: l.isupper(), o))
```

Comment: I understand you're trying to show the OP what they did wrong, but you really shouldn't use range(len(whatever)) - they might as well learn to write things Pythonically from the start. Also, there's no need to pre-initinialise i, or to compare explicitly with True.

Comment: I've added a new implementation, and adding one more pythonic way

Comment: Why are you doing `l.isupper() == True`? `l.isupper()` already evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and appreciate it.

Comment: @Ashley please accept an answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much simpler.

```
o = "the doG jUmPeD ovEr The MOOn"
upperCase = []
for letter in o:
    if letter.isupper():
        upperCase.append(letter)

print(upperCase)
```

Simply iterate over the string, it'll do so one letter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the list comphresion

```
upperCase= [ i for i in o if i.isupper() ]
```

Comment: This will get the result as a list. You should go as `''.join(i for i in o if i.isupper())` in order to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with `str.upper` as:

```
>>> o = "the doG jUmPeD ovEr The MOOn"

# Python 2
>>> filter(str.isupper, o)
'GUPDETMOO'

# Python 3
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isupper, o))
'GUPDETMOO'
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't think about this